# Hide Keyboard IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I happening the following problem:

I have two TextField, one has the default behavior, and on the other, captures the textFieldDidBeginEditing method delegate, to present a UIViewController with PresentationStyle (Custom) and TransitionStyle (CrossDissolve). So far everything works fine. But if I edit the first textField (and leave the keyboard open) and then go to the second, the keyboard is open and I have no way to close it (as if the first textField had lost focus, not even the textFieldShouldReturn is called when I press the button intro).

I tried with:

- TextFieldDidEndEditing (for calling resignFirstResponder)
- In viewWillDissaper method (I also called resignFirstResponder)

  ```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
  }

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
      print("Resign Last TextField")
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
  }

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
      print("Did Begin editing")
      if textField == self.departing || textField == self.returning{
          textField.resignFirstResponder()
          self.lastTextFieldSelected = textField

          let datePickerViewController = Util.getViewController("DatePickerViewController") as! DatePickerViewController
          datePickerViewController.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
          datePickerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
          datePickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
          datePickerViewController.datePickerDelegate = self

          self.presentViewController(datePickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
  }
  ```

Edit:
I try with self.view.endEditing(true) nothing.

I made a little example (something I check, is that textFieldShouldBeginEditing allows me to close the keyboard.):
https://github.com/Abreu0101/TextFieldBug

Comment: if you want close keyboard at viewWillDisappear for any first responder you can try self.view.endEditing(false) if it still don't close you can try  self.view.endEditing(true) , which will force close keyboard

Comment: In the situation you describe, is all your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` code actually executing?

Comment: For dismiss keyboard. Try `self.view.endEditing = true`

Comment: @matt, yes it's executing the code, but first run textFieldDidBeginEditing (in that step the first one, loose the focus), and when open the datePickerViewController (the keyboard not hide). Next, the delegate call textFieldDidEndEditing (but nothing happen).

Comment: @Pyro, anhtu, I will try that option (sometimes ago a tried that, but not in the viewWillDisapper).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `textFieldDidEndEditing` and the other methods are not even called. Make sure you set the `UITextField`'s delegate:

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Also import the `UITextFielDelegate` in your class.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have that set.